# How to read package documentation

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how to use/call libraries & functions of Golang by reading the official [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/) but couldn't fully comprehend.

Below are some examples that I hope to get advise from the experts here in SO

Example 1: [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)

From the documentation:

```
type Time
  func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time
  func Now() Time
```

I interpret the above as type `Time` has method `Now` which does not take in any input and returns a `Time` type.

thus,

```
var t time.Time
fmt.Println(t)
```

yields `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` So. `t` is a valid `time.Time` type variable.

Question 1:
But why is `t.Now()` throwing an error `t.Now undefined (type time.Time has no field or method Now)`?

Question 2:
Interestingly, `time.Now()` returns the value desired. Does that mean `Now()` is not a method of `type Time`?

Comment: `Now` is [function](https://tour.golang.org/basics/4). You are calling it as a [method](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

Comment: Take the Tour of Go which describes packages, types, functions, methods and variables in detail.

Comment: Thanks Cerise and Volker.

@Volker, I've went through Tour of Go before asking this question. I can make the code works by looking at online examples and copy-paste them but reading the documentation doesn't give me the same answer, thus needing guidance. if you know specific section, pls point out.

Comment: Thanks Cerise and Volker.

@Cerise, According to Tour of Go, 2/26, Methods says that they're functions too. But your comments made me understood a bit more. Functions means no receivers, my `t.Now()` implies that `Now()` should have a receiver infront, which is not the case as the document wrote. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Methods have receivers, functions do not.  I think your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what you are really asking here is: why is the package documentation laid out the way it is?  That is, for this specific case, in this specific package documentation, we see:

> ```
> type Time
>   func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time
>   func Now() Time
> ```

where the `type Time` line appears by itself, then immediately underneath it, several `func` declarations appear that return a value of type `Time`.

The reason these are indented two characters is to indicate that these functions return a value of type `Time`.  The reason that they appear under the `type Time` line is that these functions return a value of type `Time`.

In this case, both reasons add up to the same thing—they're redundant.  That's OK though!  It's just a function of the fact that the Go documentation generator is a program that obeys these sort and indent rules.  Nothing here implies that the two functions are receiver functions.

Consider another example from the same package documentation.  Somewhat earlier, we see:

> ```
> type Duration
>     func ParseDuration(s string) (Duration, error)
>     func Since(t Time) Duration
>     func Until(t Time) Duration
> ```

Here, this tells us that all three of these functions return a `Duration`—though the first one returns both a `Duration` *and* an `error`.  The `ParseDuration` function is an ordinary function.  It is the functions `Since` and `Until` that are *receiver functions*.<sup>1</sup>  They take a receiver argument of type `Time` (and no other arguments) and return a value of type `Duration`.

In some other design, it might make sense to sort the `Since` and `Until` functions underneath the type name `Time`, since these are receiver functions of type `Time`.  But the package documentation sorts (and groups) by *return* type, not receiver or argument type.  That's all there really is to it here.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can—and [the spec does](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations)—call these *methods* if you like.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, you understood the intent exactly: "why is the package documentation laid out the way it is ?" I wish someone told me straight that "Nothing here implies that the two functions are receiver functions".

Comment: @limecheng: if that's the answer you were looking for, consider accepting it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks @Torek, just learned about Accepting answers. 
Yup, done the Green Tick :)

Answer (score 3):

`var t time.Time` declares a variable of type `time.Time` with the zero value for the type.

`func Now() Time`: `Now()` is a function with no parameters which returns type `time.Time`

`func (t Time) Month() Month`: `Month()` is a method on the receiver `t` type `time.Time` with no parameters which returns type `time.Month`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var t time.Time
    fmt.Println(t)
    t = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
    m := t.Month()
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Ume5kxDAe05

Output:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
November
```

Note: In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC. This makes it easier to cache programs by giving them deterministic output.

Take [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).

See [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)